# Typescript interface and Promise return questions

Tags: typescript, mongoose, interface, casting, promise

Can someone explain to me the need for interface? from what I understand is making it a requirement for my schema to have the 3 fields if an instance is made. Would making a require: true; in my schema mean the same thing?

```js
   

 import { Schema, model, Document } from "mongoose";

    const schema = new Schema({
      title: String,
      description: String,
      imagePath: String
    });

    export interface IPhoto extends Document {
      title: string;
      description: string;
      imagePath: string;
    }

    export default model<IPhoto>("Photo", schema);
```

Why would I need to cast the object result from the deletion?

also, I do not understand how model("name", schema) works at all.. :(

```js
const photo = (await Photo.findByIdAndRemove(id)) as IPhoto;
```

Number 1 and Number 2 work the same, putting the type of return on the function is only to be more specific and avoid any bug? are there any other reasons for doing": Promise < Response >"?

```js
   

//number 1
    async function stuff(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response>{}


    //vs

   //number 2
    async function stuff(req: Request, res: Response){}
```

Comment: Why do you use Typescript if you don't care about a typed version of JavaScript. Typescript purpose is to serve static typing for JavaScript. If its clear what type your method or your variable is, your code will be much less error prone and also more readable. Casting the result from a database access or an api call let's you parse the result within your app more consistently and you allow some kind of contract within your application. Extracting fields manually from a JSON for exampe instead of casting it in to a js object (with the help of typescript) makes it poor design and unmanageable.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer. can you tell me what is the interface really doing on my examples? I want to be able to understand all of it.